# Small, brownish bird with reddish spot around eyes

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image: Three pictures of the bird: head, back and in flight]
This bird was seen in the Bourgoyen-Ossemeersen nature park, Ghent (Belgium) on December 3rd 2016. It is about the size of a common chaffinch.

We couldn't get a very good picture of it, unfortunately. What is the species of this bird?

Comment: From the the tree ("aulne" in French, with very typical fruits), I would have bet on this bird: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarin_des_aulnes, but is is true that the individual on the left looks much more like /Fringilla coelebs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Chaffinch (Fringilla coelebs). From the first picture you see the 
[greyish head](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3c/81/38/3c81388b13fadb96ea843bcbc5c24944.jpg) and orangish chick. From the second picture the typical whitish/greenish
[wing bars](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/3/3f/20071117152421!Fringilla_coelebs_chaffinch_male_edit1.jpg). From the third pic the [bricky belly](https://www.bto.org/sites/default/files/styles/400_wide/public/shared_images/gbw/species/chaffinch/chaffinch-birdschaffjohnharding300x207.jpg?itok=btGggYOU).